# Reformat value in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this array:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 1',
    'price' => '5',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 2',
    'price' => '$10',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 3',
    'price' => '$50',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 4',
    'price' => '20',
  ),
)
```

I need to loop through this array, reformat all prices to be in decimal format.  So example the 10 would be 10.00 and the 50 would be 50.00. I also need to make sure the $ is removed if it exists from the user submitting the value of $50

After these values are replaced. I need a array that looks just like this in the value of $result so it should look like:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 1',
    'price' => '5.00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 2',
    'price' => '10.00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 3',
    'price' => '50.00',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 4',
    'price' => '20.00',
  ),
)
```

Thanks, for all help!

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with `str_replace()` to remove the `$` and `sprintf()` to format the number as decimal.

Comment: I know how to use str replace, i dont know how to loop through the array for the specific value of price, then rebuild the array with the new values.

Comment: `foreach ($array as &$value) $value['price'] = /* reformatted $value['price'] */;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is you want :

```
$result = array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 1',
    'price' => '5',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 2',
    'price' => '$10',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 3',
    'price' => '$50',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Product 4',
    'price' => '20',
  ),
);

$output = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
   $output[$key]['name'] = $value['name'];

   //remove all characters except number and dot.. This will help to remove if instead of $ any other money format comes.
   $new_price = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $value['price']);

   $new_price = number_format($new_price, 2, '.', '');
   $output[$key]['price'] = $new_price; 

}

print_R($output);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Choose this because it removed all unwanted characters except the period. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as &$element) {
  $element['price'] = sprintf("%.2f", str_replace('$', '', $element['price'];
}
```

Putting `&` before the iteration variable makes it a reference to the actual element instead of a copy, so you can modify it in place with an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assign your array in a variable suppose $arr.

```
foreach($arr as $item=>$val)
{   
    $arr[$item]['price']=number_format(str_replace('$','',$val['price']),2);
}

 print_r($arr); // return your desire array format.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the array, trim any $ signs, and format the decimals:

```
foreach ($array as $item => $data) {

    // remove $
    $array[$item]['price'] = ltrim($array[$item]['price'], '$');

    // format decimals
    $array[$item]['price'] = number_format($array[$item]['price'], 2, '.', '');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you were asking:

```
    $arrayhelp = array (
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Product 1',
        'price' => '5',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Product 2',
        'price' => '$10',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Product 3',
        'price' => '$50',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Product 4',
        'price' => '20',
      ),
    );
```

^ Your Array V The code

```
    foreach ($arrayhelp as &$row):

        $row['price'] = number_format(str_replace('$','',$row['price']),2,'.','');
    endforeach;

    print_r($arrayhelp);
```

If you want to seperate by thousands:

```
    foreach ($arrayhelp as &$row):

        $row['price'] = number_format(str_replace('$','',$row['price']),2,'.',',');
    endforeach;

    print_r($arrayhelp);
```